# How to remove empty space above a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiimageview

So I am using a `UITableView` to display information about different films.

At the top of the VC, I have a `UIImage` which sits inside of a `UIView`. And then my table sits underneath. The table currently sits right up against the bottom of the image (which is what I want), see below:

[image]

**The Issue**

I followed a tutorial to add a simple effect, so when the user pulls down on the tableView, the image enlarges. You can see what I mean by seeing the tutorial here: [See here](http://blog.matthewcheok.com/design-teardown-stretchy-headers/)

This all worked wonderful and gave my the effect I wanted, **however**, it's now added an empty space below the image, see the image below:

[image]

Everything still works fine, and the effect works as expected, but this space is now there - which I really don't want.

The settings in the storyboard for this VC are set as followed:

[image]

The code I added to make the effect is as follows:

```
private let KTableHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 160.0 // which is the height of my UIImage
var headerView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    tableView.addSubview(headerView)

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: KTableHeaderHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -KTableHeaderHeight)
    updateHeaderView()

}
```

And then:

```
func updateHeaderView() {

    var headerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -KTableHeaderHeight, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: KTableHeaderHeight)
    if tableView.contentOffset.y < -KTableHeaderHeight {

        headerRect.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
        headerRect.size.height = -tableView.contentOffset.y

    }

    headerView.frame = headerRect

}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    updateHeaderView()

}
```

If I comment out all the code I've added, it then looks fine again, so I'm guessing it is this code that's causing the space.

I'm really keen to understand why this gap has formed, and how I can remove it, still using the code added to make the image enlarging effect.

**Update**

My UIImageView layout Attributes:

[image]

Comment: What layout attributes do you have on the `imageView` in the header?

Comment: Ah ok read the code I'll recant my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely the `private let KTableHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 160.0` line, which doesn't equal the height of the `imageView` in the header.

You need to find out the fixed height of the `imageView` after scaling, which you can get by multiplying the original image height by view width/original image width, and set the `imageView` height and `private var KTableHeaderHeight: CGFloat` to that value.

Comment: Right okay, well my image is set to a fixed size of 375x160 - so what would you suggest I should set 'KTableHeaderHeight' to? Thanks

Comment: See, that won't work for devices with screen sizes that aren't 750px wide. Could you still show what the layout attributes for the `imageView` are. And am I correct to assume that you're using the `Aspect Fill` mode?

Comment: @Nick89 "**Could you still show what the layout attributes for the imageView are**"?

Comment: sure, I can update the question with this when I'm back at my laptop. The only thing I amended though was the Aspect fill mode. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I have added an image showing the image attributes as asked for, thanks

Comment: @Nick89 **layout attributes**

Comment: Sorry, added a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

If your using a grouped UITableView then it makes a space for the group, not sure how to get rid of it.  You might want to consider making it a plan UITableView and then create the sections headers that you want via the delegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // create UIView here
}
```

However, after playing with the sample project, it seems like you can adjust your kTableHeightHeader variable in the top to adjust to hide the top section header.

I modified the sample project so you can see it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wz0ftdioz06oowc/StretchyHeaderExample2.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Hi I have added those constraints. To check this, I've just removed them and re added them, ensuring they are correct, which they are, but it's made no difference.

Comment: @Nick89 stupid question is the height of the image 160?  or is it a little smaller

Comment: hi. Yeah my image height is 160

Comment: @Nick89 i would try debugging the view hierarchy and seeing if the issue is the image isn't going back to the proper size of the view is larger than it started.  whichever one it is, you can always force it back by adding the size correct in scrollviewDidEndDecellerating

Comment: I had a good look and revised step by step, but I see no issues. I've also added your code in the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` function, but it made no difference :(

Comment: @Nick89 weird in my test that definitely forced it to the right height, something in your project must be mid shaping the height, I'll upload my sample project

Comment: that'll be helpful, thanks very much for your patience with this

Comment: Hi thanks for uploading the testing project! I think I've noticed why it's not working for me. I use a grouped tableview. And this is only on a normal 'plain' tableview. If you change the style options of your tableview to 'grouped' you'll see this no longer works. With this new information, do you have any more ideas on how to fix this? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** code:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

**Objective C** code:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```